# React Router - How to IndexRedirect to dynamic route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a situation in my React app to look like something as follows using `react-router`. I want the index of the `users/:userId` endpoint to redirect to another endpoint that includes a :userId params. What is a good way to do this? Right now the user from `currentUser` will return null because the code is only executed once in the beginning when the App is loaded the user is not yet authenticated. I'm guessing I will need to force react-router to reload the history and certain variables, or change the order of when I do authentication?

**routes.js**

```
{ /* Routes requiring login */ }
<Route onEnter={requireLogin}>
  <Route path="users" component={Users}>
    <Route path=":userId" component={User}>
      <IndexRedirect to={`/users/${currentUser().id}/profile`} />
      <Route path="profile" component={UserProfile} />
      <Route path="settings" component={UserSettings} />
      <Route path="activity" component={UserActivity} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly and you want to redirect from `/users/1` to `/users/1/profile` and `/users/2` to `/users/2/profile`, you can simply replace `${currentUser().id}` with `:userId`.

So your code would looks like this:

```
<Route onEnter={requireLogin}>
  <Route path="users" component={Users}>
    <Route path=":userId" component={User}>
      <IndexRedirect to="profile" />
      <Route path="profile" component={UserProfile} />
      <Route path="settings" component={UserSettings} />
      <Route path="activity" component={UserActivity} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Because the redirect is in the context of the route `:userId:` you can simply define your target route relative.

Comment: This does it, thanks! From the react-router docs it looked like it only accepted absolute paths.